# Using Regex in Delphi Xe with rawbytestring

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe3

In my project I need use regex to find some data inside a 400mb TMemoryStream object . Iam checking new regularexpresion inside delphi xe3 but function match only with received string parameters and not rawbytestring or pointer.
I defined the pattern on this way ok:

```
MyPatt:="\x8A\x8A(..)\x8A"
```

The problem is how to find inside the binary rawdata 
I tryied with

```
TRegex.Match((MyStreamObject.Memory)^,MyPatt);
```

but not sucess. 
I try with this and not sucess too

```
TRegex.Match(String((MyStreamObject.Memory)^),MyPatt);
```

bcz the problem is if the rawbinary object start with 0x00 is truncated.

How i can match regex expresion using pointer or rawbinarystring.?

Comment: I'd suggest to leave out that last line in your question "Any Idea, or any existing library that can help me??" because you're already asking your question in the prior sentence, and "existing libraries" is off-topic. Sorry I'm not familiar with the subject enough to provide an answer.

Comment: @JerryDodge , Thanks for the trip, main post edited.

Comment: You should use the `RegularExpressionsCore` unit, since it uses UTF8. Quote from [`help`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html): `"If you're dealing with UTF-8 data, use the RegularExpressionsCore unit to avoid needless UTF-8 to UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversions."`.

Comment: @LURD AFAIR `TPerlRegEx` as defined in `RegularExpressionsCore.pas` is just dead slow. It hardcodes options `PCRE_UTF8 or PCRE_NEWLINE_ANY` which are [very very very slow](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=495830).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use directly the RegEx library API instead of the string-based Delphi classes, which have some [identified (and not fixed) performance issues](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=495830).

For instance (compatible with Delphi 6 up to XE5):

```
uses
{$ifdef ISDELPHIXE}
  // use direct PCRE library as available since Delphi XE
  RegularExpressionsAPI,
{$else}
  // download from http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/TPerlRegEx.zip
  PCRE,
{$endif}
  SysUtils,
  ...

var
  compiled: PPCRE;
  extra: PPCREExtra;
  errMsg: PAnsiChar;
  errPos: integer;

  // here regexp points to your null-terminated regular expression
  compiled := pcre_compile(PAnsiChar(regexp),0,@errMsg,@errPos,nil);
  if reg=nil then begin
    CompileError;
    exit;
  end;
  extra := pcre_study(compiled,0,@errMsg);

  // now use the compiled pcre expression (once compiled, it is better to re-use compiled/extra values)
  found := pcre_exec(compiled,extra,pointer(text),StrLen(text),0,PCRE_NO_UTF8_CHECK,nil,0)>=0;

  // do not forget to release the compiled pcre expression
  pcre_dispose(compiled,extra,nil);
```

This code will be much faster than `TRegEx` (and its conversion from `string` to UTF-8) and `TPerlRegEx` as defined in `RegularExpressionsCore.pas` (which does not set `PCRE_NO_UTF8_CHECK` so is very slow).

You can find the original code of the above sample [in our REGEXP operator for *SQLite3* unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/05/24/REGEXP-operator-for-SQLite3).

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Could you help to show (1) how to "re-use compiled" (2) how to use the "named group" feature when RegEx library API is used directly?

Comment: (1) call pcre_exec() again with the same compiled,extra parameters, on another text (2) I do not have code to show this feature, since I do not use it, sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OP wrote about 400 MB of text. Here performance may definitively be an issue. I'm not performance-obsessed (it is the root of all evil), but if I can do something faster with no extra cost, I do it.

Comment: My point is that the issue seems to be that the RTL wrappers force conversion to UTF-8. Which is not desirable. Hence using the raw library is needed to get the correct answer. Performance is simply not relevant. Your code doesn't perform better, since the thing you are comparing against does not work. Performance comparisons are only meaningful for variants that do the same thing.

Comment: But I do thank you for opening my eyes to the possibility of calling the low-level PCRE library directly. I will store away the option in case I ever need it.

Comment: What makes the RTL wrappers slow is not only the UTF-8 conversion, but even more the fact that PCRE execution options are *hardcoded*, and `PCRE_NO_UTF8_CHECK` is not set - please see my link and [the fix proposed by Andreas - which I implmented in my answer](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=495865#495865). Still [not fixed](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108941). I suspect performance does not matter much for EMB - they will probably have written the same comment than yours: performance is simply not relevant. On 400 MB file: 1000 times faster is relevant. :)

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, Thx for good answer, and of course performance is very important for we bcz is a big stream memory object. One more question. What is the equivalent in delphi RegularExpresionAPI for python re.DOTALL, which include in search the "." even if is 0x00?.

Comment: @DavidJesus I did not dig so deep into PCRE to know if it supports null chars. I suppose  \x0 or \000  would work.

Comment: I test and work ok now, is supported null chars too. work like as a charm. Problem Solved , Thx at all.

Comment: @Anraud As I said, I feel your answer discusses performance only whilst neglecting behaviour.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So you are feeling my answer did not solve the problem? Sounds like if OP does not agree with you. :)

Comment: I said that you did not answer the question. I did not say that you did not solve the problem. You discussed performance but the question was about correctness. Your code uses different semantics and hence solves the problem. You just didn't discuss that.